# No matching function call for ostringstream `.str()`

Tags: c++, ostringstream

I have a function which is defined as

```
void writeSite(string& site, const string& contentType);
```

Now I am building my string with the `std::ostringstream` function.

After finishing the string I want to call the `writeSite` function. But I get the following error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘writeSite(std::basic_ostringstream<char>::__string_type, const char [17])’
   writeSite(body.str(), "application/json");
```

I can solve the problem if I first save the `ostringstream` to a new `std::string` variable and then call the `writeSite` function.

But I was wondering, if there is a better option?

```
  std::ostringstream body;

  body << "{";

  // some more string building

  body << "}";

  std::string sbody = body.str();

  writeSite(sbody, "application/json");
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is a prime example why a [mcve] is required. I'm halfway sure you could have found that little error yourself.

Comment: Can you change the signature of the function to `void writeSite(const string& site, const string& contentType);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
writeSite(body.str(), "application/json");
```

the string object returned by `body.str()` is *temporary*. And non-constant references can not bind to temporary objects.

A simple solution is to make the `site` argument `const` just like you have done for the `contentType` argument (which would otherwise suffer from the same problem).